# Инкремент передаваемой в функцию переменной

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять, почему не меняется значение переменной timer в первом случае, когда инкремент происходит при передаче переменной в функцию.

```js
let timer = 0;

let interval = setInterval((time) => {
    console.log(`It's: ${time}s`);
}, 1000, ++timer);

setTimeout(() =>{
    clearInterval(interval);
},4100);


let time = 0;

let newInterval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(`It's: ${++time}s\n`);
}, 1000);

setTimeout(() =>{
    clearInterval(newInterval);
},4100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let timer = 0;

let interval = setInterval((time) => {
  console.log(`It's: ${time}s`);
}, 1000, ++timer);
```

Увеличение переменной `timer` здесь происходит только один раз, в момент вычисления параметров вызова функции `setInterval`. В функцию `setInterval` третьим параметром передается значение `1`.

---

```js
let timer = 0;

let interval = setInterval((timeFunc) => {
  console.log(`It's: ${timeFunc()}s`);
}, 1000, () => ++timer);
```

Comment: Да, точно, спасибо)

Answer (score -2):

Потому что у вас префиксная форма инкремента, следовательно инкремент(увеличивается значение в момент вычисления, единственный раз) переменной, затем вычисление переменной . Подробнее https://ravesli.com/urok-40-inkrement-dekrement-pobochnye-effekty/